# Validate empty input field as the correct value in smarty

Tags: php, validation, input, smarty, field

```
<td><input type="text" name="remove" value="Remove this text"></td>
```

How can i use smarty validation directly in my template file. The correct value for the textbox is empty.

I'm trying to avoid using Javascript, and I know I can do it either in the template file or the PHP. I haven't seen any real good examples of this.

I'm confused, and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to validate your input fields if they are empty or not ? So if they are empty show an error message ?

Comment: The reverse of that. It's a spam check, if they remove the text then they prove they are human. Any other value is invalid. I wanna make sure the textbox IS empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can not validate anything using smarty. Smarty is for templating, that means: Smarty is there for generating output solely.

If you want to check if that element is empty, you have to rely on javascript or your server-sided language, e.g. PHP.

The only way to to anything roughly in your direction with smarty would be like this:

```
<td>
    {if $element_not_empty}<div class="error">Please remove the text!</div>{/if}
    <input type="text" name="remove" value="Remove this text">
</td>
```

But, of course, the variable $element_not_empty would be generated by PHP so there you are at server-sided validation again ;)